# Cannot deploy local charms after Juju upgrade

Tags: upgrade, juju

I keep getting `ERROR only charm store charm references are supported, with cs: schema` when I try to deploy charms from a local repository. My commands look like

`juju deploy -v --repository=$HOME/charm/ local:storm stormmaster`

Currently, the [deployment documentation](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/charms-deploying.html) reflects this way of doing deployments. What do I need to change to deploy my local charms?

Edit: The local repository deployment works on `1.16.6-precise-amd64` and does not work on `1.18.0-saucy-amd64`

Comment: Can you add your juju revision to the question for clarity? juju --version

Comment: can you join us in #juju on irc.freenode.net? Feel free to ping me direct @lazypower. I've got a few debugging questions to ask before I rule this as a bug.

Comment: Ok, this is a known bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1303880

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there's a workaround for this as its an undocumented change right now. There are new bits landing in the store portion of the code that have altered the behavior of "ambiguous urls"

the present workaround to make this work using your example would be:

```
juju deploy --repository=$HOME/charm local:precise/storm stormmaster
```